# How do i get API key for westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com

Tags: azure, office365, azure-cognitive-services, office365api

I am reading this link about creating custom connectors in Power Platform @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-blank  .. Now i created the custom connector as per the steps mentioned. But I am not sure from where i can get the API key to test the custom connector?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The example you are using is about you create a custom connector from scratch, without using a Postman collection or an OpenAPI definition to describe the Cognitive Services Text Analytics Sentiment API (our example for this series). Instead, you describe the connector completely in the custom connector wizard.

So, you need to have a Text Analytics service created. It's OK if you don't have a Text Analytics service, please just follow below steps:

The Text Analytics API uses an API key to authenticate users. When a user creates a connection to the API through a custom connector, the user specifies the value of this key. To get an API key:

[Request an API key to try out the API.](https://azure.microsoft.com/try/cognitive-services/?api=text-analytics) This doesn't require an Azure subscription.

[Add the Text Analytics API to your Azure subscription.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-apis-create-account) Once you have the API resource in your subscription, get the API key from the Keys section:
Go to your Azure portal -> your Text Analytics Service -> Keys and Endpoints as below screenshot.

[image]

Reference document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/#get-an-api-key